# TextView shows only first letter in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, textview, android-constraintlayout, android

In my application, I have a RecyclerView displaying products with an image and a title. The layout use a ConstraintLayout (version 2.0.0-alpha5) and the TextView width is based on the image width.
I want the title to be singleLine, so I declared maxLines=1 (I also used the singleLine attribute to see if it was the problem) and I would expect the first word to be displayed, however it is (apparently) randomly showing only the first letter.

This is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_margin="4dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/product_img_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/product_designation">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_img_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/product_img"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="V,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/img_product_sample"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_designation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:background="#FF0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/product_img_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/product_img_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/product_img_card"
        tools:text="COUTEAU PLAT 16CM BOIS"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```

My RecyclerView adapter onBindViewHolder method is as follow :

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductHolder, position: Int) {
    val product = listProducts[holder.layoutPosition]
    holder.designation.text = product.designation
    Log.d(
        "MyProblem",
        "Product.designation=[${product.designation}], textview content=[${holder.designation.text}]"
    )
    val photo = PhotosUtils.getFirstroductPicture(holder.itemView.context, product.codeArticle)
    if (photo != null) {
        val uri = Uri.fromFile(photo)
        GlideApp.with(holder.img)
            .load(uri)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image_black_24dp)
            .signature { photo.length().toString() }
            .into(holder.img)
    } else {
        GlideApp.with(holder.img)
            .load(R.drawable.ic_broken_image_black_24dp)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            //.signature { System.currentTimeMillis() }
            .into(holder.img)
    }
}
```

The picture is correctly displayed, the product.designation and the textview.text value are correct ("JERRICAN PLASTIQUE 5L" for instance) however, some times, I only have the first letter displayed in the TextView.
The background color displays a correct width.

In the screenshot below, I firstly see the word entirely of one product, then I scrolled in the RecyclerView and came back to this product who was correctly displayed and it only showed the first letter again.

[image]

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: I stopped working on this project for a while and can't reproduce the issue now